# How to turn a sequence into a sequence of tuples?

Tags: clojure

I need to read through a string (which is a sequence) 3 characters at a time. I know of `take-while` and of `take 3` and since `take` returns `nil` when there is no more input it seems like the perfect predicate for `take-while` but I cannot figure out how to wrap the string sequence so that it returns string of the next 3 characters at a time. If this was an object oriented language I'd wrap the sequence's read call or something, but with Clojure I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: See `partition` and `partition-all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `partition` or `partition-all`

```
(partition 3 "abcdef")

user=> ((\a \b \c) (\d \e \f))
```

The docs for both are

```
clojure.core/partition
([n coll] [n step coll] [n step pad coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence of lists of n items each, at offsets step
  apart. If step is not supplied, defaults to n, i.e. the partitions
  do not overlap. If a pad collection is supplied, use its elements as
  necessary to complete last partition upto n items. In case there are
  not enough padding elements, return a partition with less than n items.
nil


clojure.core/partition-all
([n coll] [n step coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence of lists like partition, but may include
  partitions with fewer than n items at the end.
nil
```

If your string is not guaranteed to be of length that is multiple of three, then you should probably use `partition-all`. The last partition will contain less than 3 elements though. If you want to use `partition` instead, then to avoid having characters from the string chopped off, you should use step=3, and a padding collection to fill in the holes in the last partition.

To turn every tuple to a string, you can use `apply str` on every tuple. So you'd want to use `map` here.

```
(map (partial apply str) (partition-all 3 "abcdef"))

user=> ("abc" "def")
```

Comment: And `partition` actually solves my next problem since I'm only interested in every other triplet of characters (ie `partition 3 3`), but I am disappointed a little that the answer turns out to be as simple as an API call and not some generic facility for decorating/adapting sequences.

Comment: @ArtB I think you want `(partition 3 6 ...)`, not `(partition 3 3 ...)`.

Comment: @Thumbnail Yes, you are correct; that was a typo on my part. I was posting from my phone working from memory. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without boxing every character:

```
(re-seq #"..." "Some words to split")

;("Som" "e w" "ord" "s t" "o s" "pli")
```

If, as your comment on [@turingcomplete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27118794/1562315) indicates, you want every other triple,

```
(take-nth 2 (re-seq #"..." "Some words to split"))

;("Som" "ord" "o s")
```

Comment: That was clever usage of re-seq and the wildcard. I'll definitely remember that.